# Sympy cannot find the laplace transform of sinh (t)

Tags: python, sympy

I have been using **sympy** for quite a few months now, and recently I have run into a problem.

The following code is supposed to calculate the Laplace Transform of **sinh(t)**.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
laplace_transform(sinh(t), t, s, noconds = True)
```

But, it fails to calculate anything and returns:  `LaplaceTransform(sinh(t), t, s)`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

(I am using `sympy-0.7.5` with `Python-2.7.7` on Windows 7 SP1 x64)

Comment: Isn't `laplace_transform` kept in `sympy.integrals.transforms`?

Comment: @alex Yes it is. But it can also be called from sympy directly. However, even if I change the first line to 

`from sympy.integrals.transforms import laplace_transform`, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it doesn't try to rewrite the function. If you do so explicitly you will find your answer:

```
>>> sinh(t).rewrite(exp)
exp(t)/2 - exp(-t)/2
>>> laplace_transform(_, t, s, noconds=True)
1/(s**2 - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the surprising thing is that `laplace_transform(cosh(t), t, s, noconds=True)` works just fine!